# If else statement to identify the last term in the array

Tags: php

I have the below code to list the Array of `terms`, I am placing a comma between the terms if there are more than one `term` assigned to the post.

```
$terms = get_terms('my_term', $args);
if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
    $count = count($terms);
    $i = 0;
    $term_list = '<span>';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '#<a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($term)) . '"><span>' . $term->name . '</span></a>';
        if ($count != $i) {
            $term_list .= ', ';
        } else {
            $term_list .= '</span>';
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would like place a `&` between the last two terms instead of a `,` if there are more than one term assigned to the post.

Comment: This question would be improved with sample data and expected output.

Comment: @miken32 IMHO the question is absolutely clear

Comment: What should be the expected result if there are only two elements in the array? Comma or &?

Comment: If there are only two terms, then there should be a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is easier to solve it with an array.

```
$terms = get_terms('my_term', $args);
if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
    $term_array = [];

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_array[] = '#<a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($term)) . '"><span>' . $term->name . '</span></a>';
    }

    if(count($term_array) > 1){
        $last = array_pop($term_array);
        $term_list = '<span>' . implode(', ', $term_array) . '</span>';
        $term_list .= ' & ' . $last;
    } else {
        $term_list = '<span>' . $term_array[0] . '</span>';
    }
}
```

**OR:**

```
$terms = get_terms('my_term', $args);
if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
    $count = count($terms);
    $i = 1;
    $term_list = '<span>';

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_list .= '#<a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($term)) . '"><span>' . $term->name . '</span></a>';

        if($i !== $count){
            if($i === $count - 1){
                $term_list .= ' & ';
            } else {
                $term_list .= ', ';
            }
        }

        $i++;
    }

    $term_list .= '</span>';
}
```

Comment: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable `if (count($term) > 1) {`

Comment: Sorry, should be count($term_array) there.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the `$count` is equal to `$i`.

```
$i = 1;
if ($count != $i) {
    $term_list .= ', ';
} else if ($count == $i) {
    $term_list .= '& ';
} else {
    $term_list .= '</span>';
}
```

Comment: If there are 3 terms, the output will be `term 1` & `term 2` & `term 3`. I wanted to have the `&` between the last two like `term 1`, `term 2` & `term 3`

Comment: @theKing you are right, check my updated answer. Changing $i = 1 would fix it.

Comment: Now I have `&` between last two terms but I have `,` after the last term like this `term 1`, `term 2` & `term 3`, We don't need that `,` after the last term.

Comment: If I have only one term, we have a `,` after the term like this `term 1`,

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$count` is equal to `$i + 1`:

```
if ($count != $i) {
    if ($count == $i + 1)
       $term_list .= '& ';
    else
       $term_list .= ', ';
} else {
    $term_list .= '</span>';
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Find the last element of the array, then just check each item within your loop against lastelement, then do your 'magic' ;).
Example:

```
$array = array('a' => 1,'b' => 2,'c' => 3);
$lastElement = end($array);
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
  echo $v . '<br/>';
  if($v == $lastElement) {
     // 'Now you know that $v is the last element, do something'; 
}
```

}